# Removing elements from C++ std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

What is the proper way to remove elements from a C++ vector while iterating through it? I am iterating over an array and want to remove some elements that match a certain condition. I've been told that it's a bad thing to modify it during traversal.

I guess I should also mention that this is an array of pointers that I need to free before removing them.

EDIT:

So here's a snippet of my code.

```
void RoutingProtocolImpl::removeAllInfinity()
{
  dv.erase(std::remove_if(dv.begin(), dv.end(), hasInfCost), dv.end()); 
}

bool RoutingProtocolImpl::hasInfCost(RoutingProtocolImpl::dv_entry *entry)
{
  if (entry->link_cost == INFINITY_COST)
  {
    free(entry);
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I'm getting the following error when compiling:

```
RoutingProtocolImpl.cc:368: error: argument of type bool (RoutingProtocolImpl::)(RoutingProtocolImpl::dv_entry*)' does not matchbool (RoutingProtocolImpl::)(RoutingProtocolImpl::dv_entry)'
```

Sorry, I'm kind of a C++ newb.

Comment: Shouldn't use `delete` instead of `free` ? `free` is a C mechanism and should not be mixed up with Object code.

Comment: Furthermore, if you have a `vector<T*>` and the vector has ownership of the objects, consider using `boost::ptr_vector<T>` instead, this way you'll make sure not to leak ;) The interface is very similar to a `vector<T>`, it just provides handling of pointers and ownership under the hood.

Comment: @garsh0p: this and your previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642671/c-compilation-error-when-passing-a-function-into-remove-if) are pretty much identical (looks copy and pasted). Please don't do that. If you want to add more detail to a question edit your existing one, or just add a comment to your question.

Comment: @Evan Teran: I was told by Brian R. Bondy below to create a new question...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
bool IsEven (int i) 
{ 
  return (i%2) == 0; 
}

//...

std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(),IsEven), v.end()); 
//v now contains 1 and 3
```

Comment: If my vector is of pointers that need to be freed after they are removed, how would I do this?

Comment: @user219847 You could wrap your pointers in a Boost:smart_ptr object.

Comment: @wheaties: Agree it's much cleaner to work with smart pointers when using STL containers especially.

Comment: in the example, the predicate IsEven could handle freeing the memory that's pointed to... It's a matter of what makes the most sense for the app you're developing... I tend to prefer for_each as its more readable -- for me.

Comment: @user219847: You could do what wheaties said, you could use boost's ptr_container library, or you could use `std::partition` (See my answer)

Comment: @Brian R. Bondy: I'm having some trouble with a compilation error. I edited my question above.

Comment: user219847: Pls post as a new question I think it's related to it being a member function.

Comment: @garsh0p: You need to use `std::mem_fun` on that.

Answer (score 24):

The vector's [`erase()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/erase/) method returns a new iterator that can be used to continue iterating:

```
std::vecor<MyClass> v = ...;
std::vecor<MyClass>::iterator it = v.begin();
while (it != v.end()) {
  if (some_condition(*it)) {
    it->cleanup(); // or something
    it = v.erase(it);
  }
  else {
    ++it;
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question, instead of describing a totally different approach. The question specifically said *while iterating through it*

Comment: Note: absolutely make sure you remember to assign `it` to the iterator returned by erase! Easy to miss, and the code still *looks* ok without it, but it dies horribly.

Comment: +1 for the same reason as kibibu, but one should prefer algorithm calls over explicit loops.

Answer (score 5):

Same as Brian R. Bondy's answer, but I'd use a functor rather than a function
pointer because compilers are better at inlining them:

```
struct IsEven : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    bool operator()(int i) 
    { 
      return (i%2) == 0; 
    };
}

//...

std::erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(),v.end(),IsEven()), v.end());
```

EDIT: In response to 
**If my vector is of pointers that need to be freed after they are removed, how would I do this?**

```
struct IsEven : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    bool operator()(int i) 
    { 
      return (i%2) == 0; 
    };
}

struct DeletePointer : public std::unary_function<myPointedType *, void>
{
    void operator()(myPointedType * toDelete)
    {
        delete toDelete;
    };
}

//...

typedef std::vector<something>::iterator Iterator_T;
Iterator_t splitPoint = std::partition(v.begin(),v.end(),IsEven());
std::for_each(v.begin(), splitPoint, DeletePointer());
v.erase(v.begin(), splitPoint);
```