# Using predicate function pointer inside a C++ class

Tags: c++, templates, containers, function-pointers, predicate

I am trying to use the solution provided in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642509/removing-elements-from-c-stdvector) question in a class. I have used "remove_if" with a predicate function inside a class.

```
    void classname::function1()
    {
    vector<NeighborPoint> neighbors;
    ....
    neighbors.erase(std::remove_if(neighbors.begin(),neighbors.end(),&classname::cannotMoveIn), neighbors.end()); 
    ...
    }

    bool classname::cannotMoveIn(NeighborPoint mp)
    {
        return !mp.inGridNotOccupied;
    }
```

That code would work if it was not in a class and the predicate was not a member function. However, now I receive long error messages which I guess refer to incompatibility of remove_if template with the predicate parameter (one error includes : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments).

**Note:** The code intends to remove the neighboring grid cells which an agent cannot  move into (out of 8 possible cells).

Does anyone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't your predicate take `NeighborPoint` as input parameter? Your vector is of the type `NeighborPoint`. Are `MoorePoint` and `NeighborPoint` related?

Comment: I am sorry. I changed the MoorePoint to NeighborPoint to make it clear when posting here but missed that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That code would work if it was not in a class and the predicate was
>   not a member function.

Of course. An instance method is not like a global function; it takes an extra hidden parameter for `this` (the object it is called on). But it seems that you don't need to use the current object at all in your function. Why did you make it an instance method in the first place?

If you don't need to use `this`, then one thing you can do is make it a static method (which is just like a regular function, except for the scope). Then you can pass it like a regular function as you did before. Even better than a predicate function is to use a function object (you have to define a functor class, which can even be a nested class if you don't want to move it out of the class) or a lambda (if you have C++11), which will allow the predicate to be inlined into the remove algorithm and thus be faster than having to call out to a function pointer each time.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed I needed to make the predicate function static.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::bind`:

```
neighbors.erase(std::remove_if(neighbors.begin(),neighbors.end(),std::bind(&classname::cannotMoveIn, this, std::placeholders::_1)), neighbors.end());
```

Moreover, as @Als pointed out, your `classname::cannotMoveIn` method takes a `MoorePoint` as an argument, while your vector contains `NeighborPoint`. Note that, even if these clases are related, you will slice the vector's objects(since you're taking the argument by value).

I believe your method should have the following signature:

```
bool classname::cannotMoveIn(const NeighborPoint &mp) const;
```

Comment: I am sorry. I changed the MoorePoint to NeighborPoint to make it clear when posting here but missed that one.

Comment: Great, then, you should anyway use the signature I provided for that method. Otherwise you will be copying objects for no reason.

Comment: Just for reference, also can use std:bind1st and std:mem_fun. `neighbors.erase(std::remove_if(neighbors.begin(),neighbors.end(),std::bind1st(std::mem_fun(&classname::cannotMoveIn),this)), neighbors.end());`

Comment: @JsDoITao both `std::bind1st` and `std::mem_fun` are deprecated in C++11.

Comment: @mfontanini Thanks for your info. Any reference to summarize C++11 changes?