# std::vector removing elements which fulfill some conditions

Tags: c++, vector, stl

As the title says I want to remove/merge objects in a vector which fulfill specific conditions. I mean I know how to remove integers from a vector which have the value 99 for instance.

The remove idiom by Scott Meyers:

```
vector<int> v;
v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 99), v.end());
```

But suppose if have a vector of objects which contains a delay member variable. And now I want to eliminate all objects which delays differs only less than a specific threshold and want to combine/merge them to one object.

The result of the process should be a vector of objects where the difference of all delays  should be at least the specified threshold.

Comment: [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove)

Comment: *"I want to eliminate all objects which delays differs only less than a specific threshold"* -- Could you elaborate on this? Differs from what? Other elements in the container? Nearby elements? Some specific value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing elements from C++ std::vector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642509/removing-elements-from-c-stdvector)

Comment: Suppose the vector contains some objects, object `o1` and object `o2` which have a delay of `o1.delay=10` and `o2.delay=50`, thus they have a relative delay of 40. This delay difference is too small to be taken into account, thus I want to consider `o1` and `o2` as one object instead of two separate objects.

Comment: @Christoph if you want to take more than one value into account, `remove_if` might be hard to use

Comment: @Christoph: And how would you want to handle this situation: `diff(o1,o2) < threshold` and `diff(o2,o3) < threshold` but `diff(o1,o3) > threshold`

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: Yes, this is the case. I want to compare on delay with all other.

Comment: @Christoph Are the delays sorted?

Comment: @Benjamin Lindley: You're right. This could lead to a degeneration of the vector to one object at worst. Maybe I have to think of this a little more.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz: yes, they are sorted.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

[`std::remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) comes to the rescue!

99 would be replaced by `UnaryPredicate` that would filter your delays, which I am going to use a lambda function for.

And here's the example:

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(
    v.begin(), v.end(),
    [](const int& x) { 
        return x > 10; // put your condition here
    }), v.end());
```

Comment: The condition can not be variable. For example putting max instead of 10.

Comment: @user1436187 uh, why not?

Comment: It would be great if you explain how can we do something like this: `v.erase(std::remove_if(
    v.begin(), v.end(),
    [](const int& x, int max) { 
        return x > max; // put your condition here
    }), v.end());`

Comment: @user1436187 it must come from outer scope. Define before the `v.erase()` call and pass to lambda inside `[]`.

Comment: You should go with Drew Dormann's answer, use std::erase_if, which is part of C++ 20

Answer (score 21):

C++20 introduces [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) for the very purpose of the objective in this question.

It simplifies the *erase-remove idiom* for [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2), and is also implemented for other standard containers, such as [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase_if) or [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase2).

Given the example in the current accepted answer:

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(
    v.begin(), v.end(),
    [](const int& x) { 
        return x > 10; // put your condition here
    }), v.end());
```

You can now make the same logic more readable as:

```
std::erase_if( v, [](int x){return x > 10;} );
//   container ^  ^ predicate
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the Standard Library also introduces appropriate versions of this function for `basic_string`, `map` etc. This should be the default choice today.

Answer (score 5):

An old question but a popular reference so I'm adding another option to this.

The `remove_if` function preserves the order of the sequence. That can be very important. However, it can also be a complete waste of time if your program doesn't care about the order.

In order to preserve the order, `remove_if` needs to shift the elements down to fill in the removed elements.

Let me introduce `partition`. Instead of shifting elements to fill in gaps, it moves an element from the end into the gap. This does **not** preserve the order, but it can be **much faster**, especially in a large array.

Here is a sample program:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Event {
  chrono::nanoseconds delay;
  string name;

  friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const Event &e) {
    return os << "{ \"delay\": " << e.delay.count() << ", \"name\": \""
              << e.name << "\" }";
  }
};

template <typename T>
ostream &operator<<(ostream &os, const vector<T> &container) {
  bool comma = false;
  os << "[ ";
  for (const auto &x : container) {
    if (comma)
      os << ", ";
    os << x;
    comma = true;
  }
  os << " ]";
  return os;
}

int main() {
  vector<Event> iv = {
      {0ms, "e1"},  {10ms, "e2"}, {11ms, "e3"}, {0ms, "e4"},
      {12ms, "e5"}, {8ms, "e6"},  {13ms, "e7"},
  };

  iv.erase(partition(begin(iv), end(iv),
                     [](const auto &x) { return x.delay > 0ns; }),
           end(iv));
  cout << iv << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

I compile it on Linux with GCC like so:
`g++ -Wall -W -pedantic -g -O3  -std=c++17  partition-test.cpp   -o partition-test`

And run it:
`./partition-test
[ { "delay": 13000000, "name": "e7" }, { "delay": 10000000, "name": "e2" }, { "delay": 11000000, "name": "e3" }, { "delay": 8000000, "name": "e6" }, { "delay": 12000000, "name": "e5" } ]`

Let me also introduce a fun command line tool named `jq` aka JSON Query:

```
./partition-test | jq 
[
  {
    "delay": 13000000,
    "name": "e7"
  },
  {
    "delay": 10000000,
    "name": "e2"
  },
  {
    "delay": 11000000,
    "name": "e3"
  },
  {
    "delay": 8000000,
    "name": "e6"
  },
  {
    "delay": 12000000,
    "name": "e5"
  }
]
```

Which is a pretty great JSON formatter also. Makes it easy to read.

Now you can see that "e7" and "e6" filled in the erased Event objects with delay == 0. And the array is no longer in order.

Answer (score 3):

Using predicate function (idiomatic way in C++11):

```
v.erase(remove_if(
            v.begin(), v.end(), bind(greater<int>(), _1, 99)),
        v.end());
```

Comment: funky `bind`, +1 for that alone.

Comment: Personally, I find lambdas make `bind` mostly obsolete. They're much more generally useful, and even in simple cases like this where `bind` would work, a lambda is much simpler both to understand, and to remember the syntax for.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Agreed.  On the other hand, if you don't have C++11, `boost::bind` is still useful.