# How to delete all tuples in a vector with a certain condition?

Tags: c++, vector, tuples

I have a vector with 3 tuples in it. I want to delete all tuples with the second value 4. this is my code:

```
int main() {

    tuple thing1 = make_tuple(1, 4, 2, 2);
    tuple thing2 = make_tuple(2, 2, 2, 2);
    tuple thing3 = make_tuple(3, 4, 2, 2);

    vector<thing> things = {thing1, thing2, thing3};

    int index = 0;
    for (vector<thing>::iterator it = things.begin(); it != things.end(); ++it) {
        if (get<1>(*it) == 4) {
            things.erase(things.begin()+index);
        } else {
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

But this code delete all of them. can anyone help me please ? Thank you so mush :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8628951/remove-elements-of-a-vector-inside-the-loop

Comment: You could use the erase remove idiom.

Comment: You have both `index` and `it` but they got desynchronized when erasure happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer adopted from [std::vector removing elements which fulfill some conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17270837/stdvector-removing-elements-which-fulfill-some-conditions). With the `remove_if` function template one could do,

```
things.erase(std::remove_if(
things.begin(), things.end(),
[](const thing& x) -> bool{ 
    return get<1>(x) == 4; // put your condition here
}), things.end());
```

See an [example](http://cpp.sh/4j2fk) at C++ Shell.