# Are there any faster way to erase elements from std::vectors?

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

I'm trying to upgrade from C to C++, and I'm having a lot of issues to get used to it. In C, I'm used to work with pointers and linked list, but that is some tiresome job. Then, I was introduced to `std::vectors`, and the world become prettier. Until I had to work with really huge vectors (a vector of 3 million of small vectors (usually some `vector<short>`)). Then my nightmare started. The operation is simply (described below).

```
vector<vector<short>> v;
v = build(); \\create all 3 million of small vectors
for(int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++){
   if(someReallyFastTest(v[i])){
      v.erase(v.begin() + i);
      i--;
   }
}
```

The program does its purpose, but takes days to finish. I tried to depurate the code and then I notice that the command

```
v.erase(v.begin() + i);
```

takes seconds to complete the task. Since in each turn I have to erase thousands of elements, it take hours to complete the task. I don't want to go back and work with pointers and linked list so soon. Is there any faster way to do this task?

Comment: Do you really need "3 million small vectors"? Can't you consolidate some of that data, or even reduce the amount of data? Or maybe at least use a single `vector` instead of a `vector` of `vector`s?

Comment: Tactical note: You may see significant performance improvement from `vector<vector<short>> v = build(); \\create all 3 million of small vectors`. The compiler can easily see that the result of `build` is only being used to initialize `v` and can take steps to eliminate copying.

Comment: If the order of your vector's elements are not important, do consider [a later answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59338794/16287) in the posted duplicate that notes that `std::partition` can be faster.

Comment: `std::vector::erase` moves every element beyond the one that’s being erased down one position. So the code in the question is O(n^2) for removing multiple elements. `std::remove_if` is linear, i.e., much better here.

Comment: If you are looking at a lot of deletions and insertions, you may want to consider using `std::list`.  Insertion and deletion are a matter of changing pointers (after the items are located), whereas a `std::vector` may have to copy all remaining items up a cell or more.

Comment: What does "depurate" mean? Did you mean profile? Or debug?

Comment: If your elements don't have to be in a particular order, you can copy the last element to the ith position and then truncate the vector by one element.